# How to prove that in an abelian group $-(-a) = a$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse

I have to prove that in an abelian group $-(-a) = a$, and the only hint given is that the inverses are unique.

My attempt is as follows:

$-(-a) = a$ is equivalent to  $-(-a) - a = 0$,  but I don't know how to continue. Some ideas?

Comment: $-(-a)+(-a)=0$ and $a+(-a)=0$

Comment: it is not neccesary a abelian group.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of inverse (of $-a$ and $a$, respectively), $-(-a)+(-a)=0$ and $a+(-a)=0$.

Therefore $-(-a)$ and $a$ are both inverses of $-a$, by definition of inverse.

Using the hint that inverses are unique, therefore, $-(-a)=a.\quad$    QED

Answer (score 2):

First, let us recall some defintions:

1. $0$ is an element such that for every element $b$,
   $$b + 0 = 0 + b = b$$
2. For any element $b$, its inverse $-b$ is an element such that
   $$b + (-b) = (-b) + b = 0$$

Start from these, we have:

$$\begin{array}{rll}
-(-a) &= -(-a) + 0  & \color{blue}{\text{ definition of } 0}\\
&= -(-a) + ((-a) + a) & \color{blue}{\text{ definition of } -a}\\
&= (-(-a) + (-a)) + a & \color{blue}{\text{ addition is associative }}\\
&= 0 + a & \color{blue}{\text{ definition of } -(-a)}\\
&= a & \color{blue}{\text{ definition of } 0}
\end{array}$$